# How do I concatenate a string with the same string in NSIS?

Tags: string, concatenation, nsis

I need to concatenate a string in NSIS that builds a new string with itself.

In C++ I would do something like this:

```
   if ( h == 0 )
      cout << "No errors\n\n";
   if ( e > 0 )
      err += e1;
   if ( f > 0 )
      err += e2;
   if ( g > 0 )
      err+= e3;
```

But in NSIS:

```
strcpy $1 "$1$2"
strcpy $1 "$1$3"
strcpy $1 "$1$4"
```

doesn't work.

Any suggestions here would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? I know it will compile, and it would be the same as lstrcat(s1,s2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
outfile test.exe
requestexecutionlevel user
page instfiles
section
;init strings
strcpy $1 "Hello: "
strcpy $2 foo
strcpy $3 bar
strcpy $4 baz

strcpy $1 "$1$2"
strcpy $1 "$1$3"
strcpy $1 "$1$4"
DetailPrint $1 ;prints "Hello: foobarbaz"
sectionend
```

Comment: Okay, I think it isn't my string concatenation that is failing but my logic in my if statements that goes into building the strings isn't happening...

I am using FindProcDLL::FindProc and doing the intcmp in the 1s being returned to build an error message stating which programs need to be closed for the installer to continue.